# PHPstorm scrolling with keyboard

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I'am looking for an option to force scroll code when entering with keyboard cursor in example at 5 line from the end.

Default behavior is to scroll code when entering 1st or last visible line of code.

I would like to change it even for 10th from the beginning and 10th before last.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the base IDE does not have an option for this. However, the behaviour is available in the [IdeaVIM plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164) [(docs)](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#ideavim) under [the `scrolloff` option.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_cursor_centered_vertically_on_the_screen)

'Scroll offset' mode can be enabled for the current session with the command:

```
:set scrolloffset=10
```

Add that to your `~/.ideavimrc` to make it permanent.

**NB:** IdeaVIM changes the IDE to behave more like [vim](http://www.vim.org/)<sup>*</sup>, which may require some re-training.

---

## If you're not familiar with Vim:

1. Install the IdeaVIM plugin (via `Settings` → `Plugins` → `Browse Repositores` → type 'ideavim' in search)
2. Restart the IDE
3. Open a file
4. Note the caret is a block like █; this indicates ['normal' mode](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes)
5. Press <kbd>:</kbd> to enter the 'command' mode
6. Type `set scrolloff=10` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
7. Scroll around, notice the editor scrolls before the caret gets to the very top (or bottom)
8. Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter 'insert' mode, and edit your file as usual
9. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to return to 'normal' mode

### Interactive vim lessons

- [openvim.com](http://www.openvim.com/)
- [vim-adventures.com](http://vim-adventures.com/)

---

<sub>* It seems difficult to have the plugin only modify the scrolloffset behaviour and leave the rest per the default IDE.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've never liked vim, so i won't use your proposal, but thanks anyway because you've confirmed that this is possible, but requires finding / writing plugin for it.

Comment: The command seems to actually be `:set scrolloff=10` (without the "set")

Answer (score 1):

You can set "EditorMoveUpAndScroll" shortcut.

Comment: In my version it is called Move Up and Scroll, but thanks a lot, it was long time since I was thinking about it, but did not search somehow how to set it up :)